# Android: Customized menu in toolbar

Tags: android

Currently, I have a spinner menu attached  to my toolbar.

**toolbar_spinner_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/overview_spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="" />
</menu>
```

I inflated the menu in my fragment by calling

**AFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_spinner_menu, menu);

    final int[] previousSelection = {0};

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.overview_spinner);
    final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, SPINNER_LIST);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Recent
                    break;
                case 1: // Now
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**R.layout.spinner_item**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="start" />
```

When an  item is selected from the spinner, the user will be prompted to select a month and year from a dialog box. **Upon clicking on "OK", the spinner's text should be updated into the choice made**.

But this is what i get when I try to update the text dynamically using the following block of code, and as you can see, the text got cut off.

```
 mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                TextView selectedText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0: // Recent
                        selectedText.setText("Since 1/8/2016");
                        break;
                    case 1: // Now
```

[image]

**What I want to achieve** is as following in the image illustration from Citymapper.

[image]

Any help rendered will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by modifying **R.layout.spinner_item** by changing `gravity` to start from `right` and setting a fixed `layout_width` in addition to some padding so it does not stick too close to the icon.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the **spinner item width**..your textview is getting too much space from the action bar rather than the space available..try lowering the **textsize** or you can remove the **title** from action bar as shown in the green one.

Comment: Didn't work by removing title, nor lowering the textsize.